# Merge url not showing up for git commit to new branch

Tags: git, github

Whenever i push to a new branch from a remote i got a message with a link like the one below but now it doesn't show up anymore. Any ideas why that is the case?

```
remote: Create a pull request for 'branch-name' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/repo/pull/new/branch-name
```

Comment: Did you try resetting your local git file?

Comment: Messages prefixed with `remote:` come from some other Git software. So either GitHub changed their software, or you or they have changed some setting that controls whether-and-when they spit that particular message at your Git to have your Git relay it to you with the word `remote:` in front. What changed? You'll need to focus on GitHub here.

Comment: I don't believe GitHub have changed their software, so it is probably some setting on the GitHub repository that is receiving your push request that has changed. What setting that is, and what it changed from and to, I have no idea.